# textbox focus not working in android device using JavaScript and phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I ve build a simple webpage using phoneGap 1.4.1 all its feature  working fine, but when i try to do focus on button onclick event it does not focus in textbox, well it work fine in desktop browsers but it is not working in andriod,here is my code.

```
document.getElementsByName('searchText')[0].value="";
document.getElementsByName('searchText')[0].focus();
```

I also place the alert at the end of this code for verification it work in andrid but it is no focusing on textbox please help.

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, but I believe there is an intentional limitation in the android browser which doesn't allow the keyboard to be triggered by script which could likely be the reason why the focus doesn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
xtype: 'textfield',
    id: 'cbarras',
    name: 'cbarras',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function() {
            Ext.getCmp("cbarras").focus();  
        },
        keyup: function(textbox, event) {
          if(event.browserEvent.keyCode==13){
            alert('enter push');
          }
       }
     }
```